# Captcha in Yii does not show "get a new code" part

Tags: php, yii

I rendered a view from a controller. The view has a captcha:

```
<?php $this->widget('CCaptcha'); ?>
```

The image is there but it does not show the "get a new code" part.

What could be the reason?

Comment: And clicking the image does not refresh it?

Comment: no it does not unfortunately

Comment: Perhaps it's your css that's hiding the link (most likely culprit - `overflow: hidden;`)? Fiddle aroung with options `clickableImage`, `showRefreshButton`, `buttonLabel` and so on.

Comment: No, i dont think they are the problem. In my opinion, it is because I am using a custom theme. It has its own css and javasctipts. What do you think about that?

Comment: I can't think of anything, there are tons of possibilities. What's the output html?

Comment: check your console ? what error you are getting ?

Comment: Ok, i solved the problem, it was because default jquery was intercepting with mine. I deleted my own and it works fine now. Thank you guys